# 500 (Internal Server Error) when changing collaborative string

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

I'm adding a chunk of characters (by copy / pasting it into the editor) to a collabortivestring but this just give error 500.

POST https://drive.google.com/otservice/save?id=1qA6DDrkUlz4BX81ReuXWgOJTN5b61LL…access_token=ya29.AHES6ZS5MsuPJConOkygYe94jez79H_A_kRByke13RT1YM3UNsQQ-9D_ 500 (Internal Server Error) api:88

Is there anything I can do to track down the root cause?